# How to implement deferred-deep-link in android

Tags: android, deep-linking

Recently, I have learned about deep linking and deferred deep linking and want to implement deferred deep linking in my app.  Provide a step by step implementation or any tutorials available for this.

Comment: Did you try to google?

Comment: check this https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/android/

Comment: @J Ramesh, It is deep linking i think. please confirm

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deep linking is a wide topic in android it was making good sense in theory but it's implementation was not perfect and we could not track any useful analytical data, This problem was solved by **[branch.io](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/android/)** initially and worked nicely,the only problem with that was it was **a third party tool and free upto a certain limit** and it **caused few issues with progaurd**, Now **google** has come out with its own implementation using firebase called **[Dynamic links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/)** I would **recommend Dynamic links over branch.io**.

**About the pricing** the dynamic links are completely [free](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) but branch.io has a limit for [free usage](https://branch.io/pricing/)

Comment: Actually, this is not completely true. Branch's deep linking product is completely free up to no limit. They only charge for premium products. It also is a much more [robust solution](https://medium.com/@andrew.thielcole/dynamic-links-in-ionic-3-firebase-vs-branch-io-573d6196a288) than firebase. I **strongly** recommend using Branch instead. And the proguard* issues @war_Hero is referring to have already been [resolved](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking/issues/373).

Comment: i beg to differ @clayjones94 that progaurd issue is still there

Comment: I suggest writing into support@branch.io is you still have issues because there is a solution.

Comment: I migrated the implementation to firebase

Comment: @clayjones94 new issue poped up in production today using branch version 2.11.1 and redirection us not happening anymore. still i believe that sdk is unastable and not backward compatible